# A bound regarding the Collatz conjecture from Wikipedia

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, conjectures, collatz-conjecture

Recently, I have been reading about the Collatz Conjecture and on the wikipedia page for it, came across the fact that:

> **Rigorous bounds**
>   Although it is not known rigorously whether all positive numbers eventually reach one according to the Collatz iteration, it is known that many numbers do so. In particular, Krasikov and Lagarias showed that the number of integers in the interval $[1,x]$ that eventually reach one is at least proportional to $x^{0.84}$.

Would anyone know where I can learn more about this bound (why $0.84$?) or where the paper was published (is it online?). Cheers

Comment: I entered `Krasikov and Lagarias` in Google, and [voila (click me)](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/krasikov.pdf)...

Comment: Two clicks search: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205002 Quote: "By computer aided proof we show that at least x^{0.84} of the integers below x contain 1 in their forward orbit under the 3x+1 map".

Comment: The bibliography at the bottom of that Wiki page has the original references.  See [19] there.

Comment: Why $0.84$? Well, more precisely why $\log_2(\lambda)=0.84175\cdots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Google search result for `Krasikov and Lagarias` is [the relevant article on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205002).